# C# - Set that returns index when adding new element

Tags: c#, .net, performance, collections, set

I am looking for a collection that matches the following conditions:

1. Elements in the collection are never repeated. That is, something `ISet<T>`-like.
2. The order of elements in the collection does not change unless elements are removed from the collection. (In my use-case I never remove any elements at all).
3. I want to be able to get the index of the element I have just added. Due to the requirement 1 that would mean: receiving the index of the element if it already exists in the collection or receiving something like `.Count` if the element does not exist.

I tried using [OrderedSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627085/HashSet-that-Preserves-Insertion-Order-or-NET) collection and then getting the index of the element with a one-liner extension method. The problem is it takes around 100ms on my machine every time I try to add a new element in a collection that already consists of couple of thousands. That is a big deal when adding lots of elements into a huge collection.

I suspect that getting the index could be done in the same place where adding the element is. Therefore, I am looking for a probably existing collection for such purpose.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would also appreciate if those who minus this question explained what did I do wrong so that I could fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably because there doesn't appear to be an attempt to solve any of this on your own. You could probably simply create your own collection; inherit from a pre-existing one that suits your needs and overload* the `Add` method to make sure the new value is unique and to return the index (aka `Count - 1`). *I don't think overload is the right word here but rather you'd probably want to use `new` to hide the existing `Add` method with this new one that returns a value. I forget what this term is called.

Comment: Expanding on that comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @sab669 that is exactly what I described in the post. First of all, I am interested if there _aIready_ _is_ a collection that fits the question. I found nothing on msdn but the problem does not look really odd to me, so I still suspect that there is no point in creating a new collection, and that is what the question is about.  But anyway, assuming the required collection does not exist. I said I tried using the custom  `OrderedSet` but because all the `Add` methods are implemented by native collections it all goes about O(n) `IndexOf` method which I don't want. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @sab669 and, of course, the reason I don't want to implement my own `Add` method is performance. Collections like  `Dictionary<T>` and  `HashSet<T>` do tricky things with  `GetHashCode()` methods for faster indexing that I don't think I would be able to implement on my own.

Comment: Ok, well you asked why you were downvoted and I'm telling you it's because you didn't post any code, you didn't ask a *specific* question but rather a set of requirements, and it doesn't sound like you've tried to solve the requirements beyond "I tried using this one class but it doesn't do what I need". If you "don't think you'd be able to implement on your own" then try that and when you get stuck ask here for help with the specifics.

Comment: @sab669 alright, I see. I actually think that problems considering industry best practices do not imply adding source code, but it explains. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so considering this problem I tried 4 solutions:

1. Making an [`OrderedSet<T>`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627085/HashSet-that-Preserves-Insertion-Order-or-NET) with an `AddWithIndex` extension method
2. Making a `HashSet<T>` with an `AddWithIndex` extension method. Although **it doesn't guarantee the order of the elements** it could still be useful in some scenarios.
3. Extending the `List<T>` class [the way JerryM proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33788756/2560087)
4. Writing my own `IndexedSet<T>` class

All of the tests were taken on the following piece of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var elements = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

    //Initialize collection here
    //...

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        //Add element to collection here
        //...
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

}
```

This test only covers the case where all elements are different and **is not really representative when you have lots of repeating elements**.

**Test 1.**
`AddWithIndex` extension method for `HashSet<T>` (it is basically the same for `OrderedSet<T>`):

```
 static class HashSetExtensions
 {
    public static int AddWithIndex<T>(this HashSet<T> set, T element)
    {
        if (set.Add(element))
        {
            return set.Count - 1;
        }
        return set.IndexOf(element);
    }

     public static int IndexOf<T>(this HashSet<T> set, T element)
     {
         int index = 0;
         foreach (var item in set)
         {
             if (element.Equals(item))
             {
                 return index;
             }
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This gave me **0.3842932 seconds** on `HashSet<T>` and **1.1972123 seconds** on `OrderedSet<T>`.

**Test 2.**
Deriving from `List<T>` the way JerryM proposed results in **7.6716346 seconds** on a collection of 20000 elements (that is 50 times less elements than in collections used for other tests) and roughly infinite time on the original 1000000 elements.

**Test 3.**
Finally, I created the following `IndexedSet<T>` collection which is basically a wrapper on both `List<T>` and `HashSet<T>`:

```
public class IndexedSet<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>, IList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list = new List<T>();
    private readonly HashSet<T> _set = new HashSet<T>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Add(T item)
    {
        if (_set.Add(item))
        {
            _list.Add(item);
            return _list.Count - 1;
        }

        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
        _set.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _set.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool remove = _set.Remove(item);
        if (remove)
            _list.Remove(item);
        return remove;
    }

    public int Count => _list.Count; 

    public bool IsReadOnly => false; 

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        T item = _list[index];
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
        _set.Remove(item);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _list[index]; }
        set
        {
            T item = _list[index];
            _set.Remove(item);

            _list[index] = value;
            _set.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This gave me **0.3558594 seconds** (that is even a bit faster than extension for `HashSet<T>`) and guaranteed the order of the elements (just like `OrderedSet<T>`).

Hopefully, this would be useful for someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public class SpecialList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new int Add(T Item)
    {
        if (Contains(Item))
        {
            return IndexOf(Item);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Add(Item);
            return Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be even slower than `HashSet<T>` when adding new elements? Anyway, I will check the performance and tell the result.

Comment: It doesn't matter too much, but you actually don't even need the `else` block here. If the software hits the `if` block, it'll return. If not, then it's going to continue on. Anything to remove "unnecessary" braces and lines, in my opinion (and I think resharper would probably recommend this as well)

Comment: I don't know how well  this approach will perform. It depends on how often the Add method is called when the item is already in the list vs when it is not. Once you know that, there might be a better way to go. Be wary of premature optimization. And although HashSets are optimized for testing for set membership, they don't maintain order--which I believe is one of your requirements.